# inner join + count + group by

Tags: mysql, count, group-by, inner-join

I'm have trouble counting/grouping the results of an inner join

I have two tables

1. `results_dump`: Which has two columns: `email` and `result` (the result value can be either `open` or `bounce`)
2. `all_data`: Which has three columns: `email`, `full_name` and `address`

The first goal is to query the result_dump table and count and group the number of times the result is `"open"` for a specific `email`.

This query works great:

```
SELECT `email`, COUNT(*) AS count
FROM `result_dump`
WHERE `date` = "open" 
GROUP BY `email`
HAVING COUNT(*) > 3
ORDER BY count DESC
```

The second goal it to take those results (anyone who "open" more then 3 time) and pull in the 'full_name' and 'address' so I will have details on who opened an email 3+ times.

I have this query and it works as far as getting the data together - But I can't figure out how to get the `COUNT`, `HAVING` and `ORDER` to work with the `INNER JOIN`?

```
SELECT *
FROM all_data
INNER JOIN result_dump ON 
all_data.email = result_dump.email
where `result` = "open"
```

Comment: well, you would need to reference the groupable object correctly.  Are you doing that?

example:   select a.email, count(*) as count from A a inner join B b on a.id=b.id where a.result = 'open' group by a.email have count(*) >= 3, order by count(*) desc

Comment: It took my a few hours to understand (i'm new to this) - it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT email,name,count(*)
FROM all_data
INNER JOIN result_dump ON 
all_data.email = result_dump.email
where `result` = "open" 
group by result_dump.email
having count(*)>3
ORDER by count DESC
```

Nothing wrong with this one I think.

Answer (score 1):

Try with following query:

```
SELECT * FROM all_data AS a
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT * FROM result_dump where email IN 
                                    (SELECT `email`
                                     FROM `result_dump`
                                     WHERE `date` = "open" 
                                     GROUP BY `email`
                                     HAVING count(email) >3
                                     ORDER BY count(email) DESC)) AS b
ON a.email = b.email
WHERE b.`result` = "open"
```

Comment: I tired this it gave me "Every derived table must have its own alias" error - On your first line should "SELECT * FROM all_data a" be SELECT * FROM all_data as ____" I'm not sure what should be there

Comment: Not working yet, but I will take a day to really go through it, very good chance I'm making an error somewhere - thanks

Comment: SELECT *, count(*) as count from `result_dump` AS a 
inner join `all_data` 
AS b on a.email = b.email
where a.result_dump = 'open'
group by a.email

Answer (score -1):

**This is Works Fine...!** Try to this..

```
SELECT title.title
       ,count(*)
       ,title.production_year
       ,title.id as movie_id
       ,title.flag as language
       ,movie_info.info
FROM title INNER JOIN movie_info ON title.id=movie_info.movie_id;
```